# can the key used in chrome storage API set calls be a variable?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, storage

I am trying to use the [Chrome Storage API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) and want to use a key that is determined at runtime. However, when I try something like

```
    var d = 'random string';
    chrome.storage.sync.set({d : actual_data});
```

The key that seems to be stored is the actual character 'd' and not the value of the string that is assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set keys in JavaScript objects with variables.  You must use bracket notation to do this.

```
var obj = {}, d = 'random string';
obj[d] = actual_data;
```